# How to determine if device supports 802.11ac?

Tags: wi-fi

How to I determine if an Android device supports [802.11ac](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=7461) (5Gz WiFi)?

Comment: Read the device specification. A pretty useful device database is for example https://gsmarena.com/

Comment: @Robert BLU V50 doesn't appear in that database.

Comment: https://www.droidafrica.net/blu-v50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [CPU Info](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.kgurgul.cpuinfo/)'s Hardware tab, item "WiFi 5Ghz".

Answer (score 0):

goto Settings - WiFi - show available networks. if you see 2.4G/5G your device supports it

[image: wifi]

Comment: I don't see any 2.4 or 5G icons on mine. I'm wondering if the hardware is 802.11ac capable and the software is disabling it. The BLU V50 is a fairly recent, low-end phone (a 2013 Galaxy S4 supports 5GHz).

Comment: That 2.4G/5G badge seems to be a proprietary modification of your phone manufacturer, because on my Pixel 4a stock Android 12 such badges do not exist.